# Complex LogIntegral error

Tags: special-functions, complex, number-theory

Going through Derbyshire's Prime Obsession & trying to take `LogIntegral` of `20^ZetaZero[1]` & comes up with a value of `1.99797 - 3.91384 I` instead of `-0.105384 + 3.14749 I` quoted in the book. Am I doing something wrong?

Is it something to do with discrepancy between American definition of `LogIntegral` & European?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note the chapter on the zeta function in Wagon's Mathematica In Action, where he refers to a book by H.M. Edwards called Riemann's Zeta Function. Wagon cautions that`ExpIntegralEi[r Log[x]]`must be used instead of`LogIntegral[x^r]`when x is real and r is complex. This is because the complex log function returns `r Log[x]-2 Pi n i`, with`n`chosen to make the imaginary part lie between -Pi and Pi, which leads to incorrect sums. For example,

```
N[ExpIntegralEi[ZetaZero[1] Log[20]]]
```

returns `-0.105384 + 3.14749 I`

Comment: Thank you for that reference & the explanation :)

Comment: ... Just looked at it on Amazon - think I need to buy a copy