# Range of summation in simple Plot seems off

Tags: plotting, special-functions, summation, number-theory

I was trying to reproduce a picture in a [book by Havil](http://books.google.com/books?id=OLPGmPz0rB8C&pg=PA198) of the sum,

$$s = \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(r)}{r}\left(Li(x^{\rho_k/r})+Li(x^{\rho_k*/r})\right) $$

using

```
s = Sum[(MoebiusMu[i]/i)*(LogIntegral[x^(ZetaZero[1]/i)] + 
      LogIntegral[x^(Conjugate[ZetaZero[1]]/i)]), {i, 1, 30}];
```

The graph,

```
Plot[s, {x, 10, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

looks qualitatively somewhat like the original for $k = 1$ but the range is too large and not as symmetric about $y = 0.$ The range, per Havil, is about $(-0.3, 0.3)$ as opposed to the range of about $(-3, 8)$ of the code above.

I tried increasing the number of terms but this doesn't seem to affect the picture much.

Comment: I wonder if you could scan and post the formula and the plot (just that)

Comment: Well, the output from Mma is quite asymmetric and in the `(−3,8)` range ... yes. Without access to the book IDT one can say more ...

Comment: @belisarius: Perhaps not. Thanks for the edits and check of the range. If I get access to a scanner I will add the graphs. Or if someone who has the book can confirm that my description of the range is correct--the graph is on p. 198, upper left (his $T_1$).

Comment: A tip I can give right now: you will want to use `ExpIntegralEi[a Log[x]]` here instead of `LogIntegral[x^a]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `Txk[x,k,n]` calculates the contribution of the `k^th` zero at position `x`. The parameter `n` governs how many terms in the sum are used. This corresponds to Havil's equation on the bottom of page 196 of his book Gamma. Note that `ExpIntegralEi` should be used as @J.M. suggests, and as discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43238/complex-logintegral-error/43240). I think there is a typo in the book, hence the argument to `ExpIntegralEi` is divided by the summation index.

```
Txk[x_?NumericQ, k_Integer, n_Integer] :=
   Module[{rlogx = ZetaZero[k]*Log[x], 
          mm = MoebiusMu[Range[n]], rn},
          rn = Flatten[Position[mm, _?(# != 0 &)]];
          -2*((mm[[rn]]/rn).Re[ExpIntegralEi[rlogx/rn]])]
```

For example, the following is the top row of plots on page 198.

```
Plot[Txk[x, 1, 100], {x, 10, 100}, Frame -> True, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, FrameLabel -> {"x", ""}, 
     PlotLabel -> "T[x,k=1]", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]
```

[image: contribution of zeros 1 and 2]

Comment: I think those plots also appeared in Wagon's book…

Comment: Yes, these plots are on page 552 of the second edition of Mathematica in Action. The equation he uses is on page 549, which should have a minus sign in front. Equation (***) on top of page 550 is correct, and it includes a sum of 154 terms, which is an approximation justified by [Riesel and Gohl, Mathematics of Computation, v24, p969, 1970](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1970-0277489-3). I think, but Stan may not agree with me, that in general the upper limit of the sum should be `Floor[Log[2,x]]`.

Comment: The typo was in my question (in the formula but not the code), not the book. Corrected now. Helpful answer and references and tip.

Comment: @daniel That's why I asked for the book scan. :(

Comment: @belisarius: If I had access to a scanner I would have provided one. I understood why you asked for a scan. As it turns out the question was answered without it but I certainly don't disagree that would have been ideal.

Comment: @daniel No problem. Glad to see you got a very nice answer!