# Riemann Prime Counting Function correction/pairing terms by Mathematica

Tags: special-functions, number-theory, prime-numbers

Riemann Prime Counting Function:

$$f(x)=\operatorname{li}(x)-\sum_\rho\operatorname{li}(x^\rho)-\ln 2+\int_x^\infty \frac{\mathrm dt}{t(t^2-1)\ln t}$$

The second correction/paring terms:

$$\sum_\rho\operatorname{li}(x^\rho)=\sum_{I[\rho]>0}[\operatorname{Li}(x^\rho)+\operatorname{Li}(x^{1-\rho})]$$

I tried to use Mathematica function `LogIntegral` to plot this second correction/paring terms, for example, when I only include the first 2 non-trivial zeros, and plot with range x from 1 to 5:

[image: code]

```
Plot[Sum[LogIntegral[x^ZetaZero[k]] + LogIntegral[x^(1 - ZetaZero[k])],
     {k, 1, 2}], {x, 1, 5}]
```

However, I got very large value instead of small correction:

[image: bad plot]

I can also use simplified equation provided by [reference 1](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1970-0277489-3):

$$\operatorname{li}(x^\rho)=\operatorname{li}(e^{\rho \log x})\sim \frac{e^{\rho \log x}}{\rho \log x}$$

[image: code]

```
Plot[Sum[Exp[ZetaZero[k]*Log[x]]/(ZetaZero[k]*Log[x]), {k, 1, 2}] +
     Sum[Exp[(1 -ZetaZero[k])*Log[x]]/((1 - ZetaZero[k])*Log[x]),
         {k, 1, 2}], {x, 1, 5}]
```

Then I got the correct result:

[image: good plot]

Anyone knows what is wrong for the `LogIntegral` one?

Thank you!

[1: H. Riesel and G Gohl, "Some Calculations Related to Riemann's Prime Number Formula," Mathematics of Computation, 24(112), 1970 pp. 969–983.](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1970-0277489-3)

Comment: `RiemannR` is built in so you could always use that. One reason your correction is bad is because $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ is not the same as $\mathrm{li}(x)$. You should code $\mathrm{li}(x)$ as `LogIntegral[x]`, but $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ as `LogIntegral[x]-LogIntegral[2]` , however there is still something else wrong as the correction is still too large.

Comment: Thanks. yeah, by adding `- LogIntegral[2]` doesn't give the correct answer. It just shift the trend a little bit down. `RiemannR` only gives the mobius function of first major prime counting term. It does not contain the correction terms. therefore if you plot `RiemannR`, only a smooth counting curve could be generated, instead of a "zigzag" curve following the real prime number distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see the explanation in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43238/complex-logintegral-error/) question.

```
Plot[
     Sum[
         ExpIntegralEi[ZetaZero[k]*Log[x]] + 
         ExpIntegralEi[(1 - ZetaZero[k])*Log[x]],
     {k, 1, 2}], {x, 1, 5},
Frame -> True]
```

The corresponding plot matches the one you showed from the "simplified equation".

[image: Riemann plot]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!